# How to identify the bitrate of audio streaming to HomePod

Tags: audio, streaming, homepod

On a [HomePod (2nd generation)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePod#Second_generation) I often [stream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Consumerization_of_streaming) (a) radio stations such as [KNKX FM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KNKX), and (b) music services such as [SomaFM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SomaFM).

Is there way to inspect the [bit-rate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate) and [compression method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_coding_format) (such as [AAC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding)) of the stream?

And for sources that offer a choice of bit-rate and compression methods, is there any way to choose between them on a HomePod?

Comment: Wireshark is a packet inspection tool that should allow you to see what is going out to which endpoint. But it is not for the faint of heart and requires quite a bit of network engineering expertise to understand what it is showing you.

Comment: I never thought of doing that with a HomePod, it's an excellent idea which should be proposed if it doesn't have a solution yet.